# how to merge multi string to one string in php

Tags: php, string

I have a string "`$TransactionId`" with this values:

```
string 'aa,' (length=2)

string 'bb,' (length=2)

string 'cc,' (length=2)

string 'dd,' (length=2)

string 'ee,' (length=2)

string 'ff,' (length=2)
```

i want to merge this values to one string like this:

```
string 'aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff'
```

Help me!thank you.

Edit:

`$TransactionId` id response from a web service in a loop like this:

```
for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){
$TransactionId  = $result->getTransactionId();
}
```

Comment: `implode($glue, $parts)` maybe?

Comment: Are you sure `$Transactionid` is a string? looks like an array of strings to me.

Comment: update your question to show where `$Transactionid` comes from and how you provided that output

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @AlexAndrei edit my question

Comment: @RajdeepPaul edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `var_dump` output suggests that the webservice doesn't return the value with a trailing comma

```
string 'ff,' (length=2)
```

This should say `(length=3)`

Just build an array containing the ids inside the loop then `implode` it using comma as a separator

```
for($i=1;$i<=$num;$i++){
    $ids[] = $result->getTransactionId();
}

$finalString = implode(',',$ids);

print $finalString;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you could store your strings into an array:

```
$arr = array('aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff');
```

And then use implode:

```
$string = implode(',', $arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can concat string and remove last comma using  function

```
<?php rtrim("'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff',", ",") ?>
```

you can also remove using substr function

```
<?php substr("'aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff',", 0, -1); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your sample data strings.

```
$a='aa,';
$b='bb,';
$c='cc,';
$d='dd';
```

addStringsToArray() function will accept any number of arguments.
Loop foreach argument/string passed in the function and push them to $stringItems array.

```
function addStringsToArray(){
    /* Declare empty array */
    $stringItems = array();      
    /**  Returns the number of arguments passed to the function */
    $numOfArgs = func_num_args();
    /** Returns an array with all arguments passed to the function */
    $listOfArgs = func_get_args();
/** Add strings to array */
for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfArgs; $i++) {
    array_push($stringItems ,$listOfArgs[$i]);
}
// Returns array with items 
return $stringItems;}
```

implode returned $stringItems array

```
echo implode(" ",addStringsToArray($a,$b,$c,$d));
```

Your Output:

```
aa, bb, cc, dd
```

OR

addStringsToString() function will accept any number of arguments.
Loop foreach argument/string passed in the function and add them to $stringItems string .

```
function addStringsToString() {
    $stringItems = "";      
    $numOfArgs = func_num_args();
    $listOfArgs = func_get_args();
/** Add strings to string */
for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfArgs; $i++) {
    $stringItems.=$listOfArgs[$i];
}
// Returns String
return $stringItems;
```

}

Call function and return $stringItems string

```
echo addStringsToString($a,$b,$c,$d);
```

OUTPUT :

```
aa,bb,cc,dd
```

Comment: Code-only answers are frowned upon at SO. Please include an explanation of how your code answers the question, in addition to the code.